# Kivy MD DropDownItem: how to set the item of a dropdownitem into another dropdownitem

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to developed a simple GUI in Kivy MD / Python. Originally, I modified the [example code](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Components-DropDownItem):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.dropdownitem import MDDropDownItem
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

KV = '''
MDScreen

   MDDropDownItem:
       id: drop_item_1
       pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}
       text: 'FREQUENCY_1'
       on_release: app.menu_sampling_rate_1.open()
       
   MDDropDownItem:
       id: drop_item_2
       pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
       text: 'FREQUENCY_2'
       on_release: app.menu_sampling_rate_2.open()
'''


class MainApp(MDApp):
   sampling_rate = ['300 Hz', '200 Hz', '100 Hz']   
   
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
       
       self.menu_sampling_rate_1, self.sampling_rate_items_1 = self.Create_DropDown_Widget(self.screen.ids.drop_item_1, self.sampling_rate)
       self.menu_sampling_rate_2, self.sampling_rate_items_2 = self.Create_DropDown_Widget(self.screen.ids.drop_item_2, self.sampling_rate)
               
   
   def Create_DropDown_Widget(self, drop_down_item, item_list):
       items_collection = [
           {
               "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
               "text": item_list[i],
               "height": dp(56),
               "on_release": lambda x = item_list[i]: self.Set_DropDown_Item(drop_down_item, menu, x),
           } for i in range(len(item_list))
       ]
       
       menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=drop_down_item, items=items_collection, width_mult=2)
       menu.bind()
       
       return menu, items_collection


   def Set_DropDown_Item(self, dropDownItem, dropDownMenu, textItem):
       dropDownItem.set_item(textItem)
       dropDownMenu.dismiss()  


   def build(self):
       return self.screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
   MainApp().run()
```

I tried to slightly modify it using a class *View* in which all methods and properties related to the interface are included.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.dropdownitem import MDDropDownItem
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

KV = '''
<View>:
    orientation: vertical

    MDDropDownItem:
        id: drop_item_1
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}
        text: 'FREQUENCY_1'
        on_release: root.menu_sampling_rate_1.open()
        
    MDDropDownItem:
        id: drop_item_2
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
        text: 'FREQUENCY_2'
        on_release: root.menu_sampling_rate_2.open()
'''



class View(MDBoxLayout):
    sampling_rate = ['300 Hz', '200 Hz', '100 Hz']      
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.menu_sampling_rate_1, self.sampling_rate_items_1 = self.Create_DropDown_Widget(self.ids.drop_item_1, self.sampling_rate)
        self.menu_sampling_rate_2, self.sampling_rate_items_2 = self.Create_DropDown_Widget(self.ids.drop_item_2, self.sampling_rate)
        
                
    def Create_DropDown_Widget(self, drop_down_item, item_list):
        items_collection = [
            {
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "text": item_list[i],
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x = item_list[i]: self.Set_DropDown_Item(drop_down_item, menu, x),
            } for i in range(len(item_list))
        ]
        
        menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=drop_down_item, items=items_collection, width_mult=2)
        menu.bind()
        
        return menu, items_collection    
    

    def Set_DropDown_Item(self, dropDownItem, dropDownMenu, textItem):
        dropDownItem.set_item(textItem)
        dropDownMenu.dismiss()   


class MainApp(MDApp):    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.view = View()

    def build(self):
        return self.view


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

My questions are:

1. In this second version, with the *View* class, why I get the *AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'*?
2. How to set the item of a dropdownitem equal to the current item of the second dropdownitem and viceversa? In this way when the user selects a new item into a dropdownitem, this new selection appears also into the other dropdownitem.So the two dropdownitem show the same current item.
3. How to set the width of a dropdownitem equal to dp(80)? The approach based on *size_hint_x* and *width* seems to not work.
4. Is there a way to enable/disable a dropdownitem? The property *active* seems to not work.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> In this second version, with the View class, why I get the
> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'getattr'?

Because at the moment of executing **init** of class View(MDBoxLayout) you dont have anything in self.ids

If you try it in debug you will see it:
[image]

Solution here to create widgets after Kivy created own objects, in you first example you do it in MainApp class and thats ok.

> How to set the item of a dropdownitem equal to the current item of the
> second dropdownitem and viceversa? In this way when the user selects a
> new item into a dropdownitem, this new selection appears also into the
> other dropdownitem.So the two dropdownitem show the same current item.

If you want to change another widget(s) - just use ids to change them after you changed first one. Example of possible implementation:

```
    def Set_DropDown_Item(self, dropDownMenu, textItem):
       wanted_dropdowns = ('drop_item_1', 'drop_item_2')  # ids of widgets you want to modify
       for dropdown in wanted_dropdowns:
           self.screen.ids[dropdown].set_item(textItem)
       dropDownMenu.dismiss()
```

> How to set the width of a dropdownitem equal to dp(80)? The approach
> based on size_hint_x and width seems to not work.

Widget size changes to fit text, so maybe font_size: "80dp" is what you want.

[image]

> Is there a way to enable/disable a dropdownitem? The property active
> seems to not work.

Use disabled property. In python:

```
    def disable_widget(self, widget):
       widget.disabled = True
```

In kv

```
  disabled: 'True'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first two questions still remain unclear to me. How to create widgets after Kivy created its own objects? How to set an item into drop_item_2 corresponding to the current_item selected into drop_item_1? I tried with this line of code added into the Kv section: _select: app.Set_DropDown_Item(drop_item_2, app.menu_sampling_rate_2, self.current_item)_. Even if I added it into the first code version (see above), I get an 'AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'menu_sampling_rate_2''. But I still need to adopt the second code version with the _View_ class!

Comment: Considering the third question, modifying the _font_size_ is not a proper solution to set the width of the widget because it also change the height. Moreover the widget has still an adjustable size. I would like to have a drop down item with fixed width.